# Async Task using RxJava2 in Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, rx-java

I have tried to create the async task using the RxJAVA2. The code is working fine. WHat enhancement can I do in this code?

```
private void createObservable(){


         progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(ProductActivityRx.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Data fetching...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        Observable<List<Product>> booksObservable =Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Product> call() throws Exception {
                return getProductList();
            }
        }).doOnNext(new Consumer<List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<Product> strings) throws Exception {
            }
        });

        productSubscription = booksObservable.
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribe(new Consumer<List<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<Product> productList) throws Exception {

                        displayData(productList);
                    }
                });

    }
```

I am updating the UI in displayData().

Answer (score 1):

1. in general, I believe it would be better if you included this in some sort of chain. What I mean here:

   - don't return void, rather an `Observable`
   - don't show the progress dialog in the function, rather delegate it to the part responsible for UI. Same with `displayData()`
   - where's the whole function called? What calls it? Where is it located, in an Activity?
2. `doOnNext()` can be gotten rid of - there's no action in here
3. Are you getting just one result at a time? I mean, is the function called perpetually on and on and on, and you just evaluate the result each time? Perhaps you could use `Single` or `Maybe`, which is better suited for single results.

Good luck and hope we'll both learn something along the way.